# What happens to my votes I cast when I was <15?

Tags: support, new-users, up-votes

I joined SE network sites. As I am new, I have low reputation. As a part of contribution, I cast votes.

But when I cast votes, I see the following message.

[image: Message]

Today, I gained 15 reputation on money.stackexchange. Then I cast votes and those reflected immediately; the earlier message disappeared. That means my votes are being reflected now immediately.

Looking at the message above, I was assuming that my votes are being recorded. It's just that those are not visible publicly.

When I go to my *Activity* section of my profile, I see following:

[image: Profile]

That section shows I only cast two votes. I have cast those two votes after I got 15 reputation. I do not see the vote count for those I cast before that.